# /api/v1/search/order - Sw 6.2.2 - Internal Server Error

Tags: api, internal-server-error, shopware

I am using /api/v1/search/order Api in shopware 6.2.2.

These are my parameters

```
{
   "page":1,
   "limit":10,
   "filter":[
      {
         "type":"range",
         "field":"orderDate",
         "parameters":{
            "gte":"2020-03-9"
         }
      }
   ],
   "aggregations":[
      {
         "type":"histogram",
         "name":"order_count_month",
         "field":"orderDateTime",
         "interval":"day",
         "aggregation":{
            "type":"sum",
            "name":"amountTotal",
            "field":"amountTotal"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I am getting the following errors

> {
>       "errors": [
>           {
>               "code": "0",
>               "status": "500",
>               "title": "Internal Server Error",
>               "detail": "Notice: Undefined index: amountTotal",
>               "meta": {
>                   "trace": [
>                       {
>                           "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/System/SalesChannel/Api/StructEncoder.php",
>                           "line": 118,
>                           "function": "encodeStruct",
>                           "class": "Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Api\StructEncoder",
>                           "type": "->",
>                           "args": [
>                               {
>                                   "key": "2020-04-29 00:00:00",
>                                   "count": 1,
>                                   "extensions": [],
>                                   "amountTotal": {
>                                       "sum": 19.99,
>                                       "extensions": []
>                                   }
>                               },
>                               1,
>                               {}
>                           ]
>                       },

How can I fix this?

This error also exists in the Shopware dashboard. so the sales, order graphs are not showing in Shopware 6.2.2 dashboard.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to fix this?

Comment: This error is also in Shopware 6.2.2 dashboard. so the graph is not showing in dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Your API need to have "totalAmount" defined, and you dont pass it, check in the documentation or your code where this parameter is expected.

Comment: This is Shopware default API. I am just using it.

Comment: I cant found a endpoint /api/v1/search/order , do you have the link of this endpoint documentation ?

Comment: I am using admin API.

Admin API authentication
https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/admin-api-guide/authentication?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/admin-api-guide

Reading entities.
https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/admin-api-guide/reading-entities?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/admin-api-guide.

No separate documentation for orders but we can read the order entity.

Comment: If you want to see the API call and error

Please install the Shopware 6.2.2 version and take the admin dashboard.
Check with your inspect element tool (Network tab)

you can see a request 
https://yourdomain.com/api/v2/search/order. (500 Internal Server Error)

Comment: Post me the code between the line 85 and 120 of "/var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/system/saleschannel/api/structencoder.php"

Comment: This is the file https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.2/src/Core/System/SalesChannel/Api/StructEncoder.php